# Vim inserting C style comments

Tags: vim, c, vimscript

`:command Linecomment :normal ^i/*<ESC>$a*/<ESC>`
The above command is one that I came up with in order to comment out an entire line in C, normally for debugging purposes and whatnot.

I was wondering what sort of modifications would be needed to turn this into a function, and what similar function would comment from the cursor position to the end of the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To factor out a function (which is useful when the mapping commands become longer), the only thing you need to consider is that the special keys like `<Esc>` that work in the right-hand side of the mapping don't work inside the function; you need to use `:execute` with double-quotes, and escape them:

```
function Linecomment()
    execute "normal ^i/*\<ESC>$a*/\<ESC>"
endfunction
command Linecomment call Linecomment()
```

To comment from the cursor position, you just need to drop the `^` motion at the start.

However, for a truly powerful and robust commenting solution, I would recommend to use one of the popular plugins:

- [The NERD Commenter - A plugin that allows for easy commenting](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218)
- [tComment - An extensible & universal comment plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173)
- [commentary.vim - Comment stuff out; takes a motion as a target](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3695)

Comment: Thank you for this. I grabbed The NERD Commenter and it works great. took me a minute to figure out how to install plugins, but now it works exactly as I wanted!

Comment: Here are some examples of NERD Commenter usage for C files: https://superuser.com/questions/781590/vim-c-line-comment-function/1446653#1446653