# Vim C line comment function

Tags: vim

The following function in `~/.vimrc` is to comment out C line, and it works perfectly.

```
function CLC()
    execute "normal ^i/*\<ESC>$a*/\<ESC>"
endfunction
```

But I have two questions...
1. How do I make it comment out a *range* of lines.
2. How can I make it comment them out like this:

```
/*  
 * multiline   
 * comment   
 *   
 */
```

I am aware of the NERDCommenter plugin that would do both of these for me, but one of the mappings conflicts with the mapping for another plugin I have.

Comment: thats a poor reason to not use the plugin. You can always change the mappings.

Comment: I haven't got the slightest idea how to change mappings

Comment: It doesn't appear that NERDCommenter supports a custom leader but you can ask on the github page for a configurable mapping. Or just modify the source code. You want to change one of the `s:CreateMaps` lines.

Comment: I can't even figure out how to modify the source...there's folded code or something, and I have never dealt with folding before

Comment: Actually just read `:h NERDComMappings` (assuming you have NERDCommenter installed and run help tags) This tells you how to create custom mappings

Answer (score 3):

`:help NERDComMappings` tells you how to change NERDCommenter's default mappings. For instance, put this into your `~/.vimrc` to change the mapping prefix to `<Leader>C`:

```
nmap <Leader>Cc <Plug>NERDCommenterComment
xmap <Leader>Cc <Plug>NERDCommenterComment
nmap <Leader>C<Space> <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle
xmap <Leader>C<Space> <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle
nmap <Leader>Cm <Plug>NERDCommenterMinimal
xmap <Leader>Cm <Plug>NERDCommenterMinimal
nmap <Leader>Cs <Plug>NERDCommenterSexy
xmap <Leader>Cs <Plug>NERDCommenterSexy
nmap <Leader>Ci <Plug>NERDCommenterInvert
xmap <Leader>Ci <Plug>NERDCommenterInvert
nmap <Leader>Cy <Plug>NERDCommenterYank
xmap <Leader>Cy <Plug>NERDCommenterYank
nmap <Leader>Cl <Plug>NERDCommenterAlignLeft
xmap <Leader>Cl <Plug>NERDCommenterAlignLeft
nmap <Leader>Cb <Plug>NERDCommenterAlignBoth
xmap <Leader>Cb <Plug>NERDCommenterAlignBoth
nmap <Leader>Cn <Plug>NERDCommenterNest
xmap <Leader>Cn <Plug>NERDCommenterNest
nmap <Leader>Cu <Plug>NERDCommenterUncomment
xmap <Leader>Cu <Plug>NERDCommenterUncomment
nmap <Leader>C$ <Plug>NERDCommenterToEOL
xmap <Leader>C$ <Plug>NERDCommenterToEOL
nmap <Leader>CA <Plug>NERDCommenterAppend
xmap <Leader>CA <Plug>NERDCommenterAppend

nmap <Leader>ca <Plug>NERDCommenterAltDelims
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sexy C comments mode**

Ranges of lines just work by default with visual selection + `<leader>cc`, tested on 2.5.2.

But above all, I want to highlight in this answer the "sexy mode" comments with `<leader>cs`, which generates nice C multiline comments.

For example, if you start with:

```
This is a c style sexy comment
So there!
```

then `<leader>cs` from visual selection transforms it into:

```
/* This is a c style sexy comment
 * So there! */
```

And you can also switch to non-compact mode by adding to your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:NERDCompactSexyComs = 0
```

which works as follows:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                                                         *'NERDCompactSexyComs'*
Values: 0 or 1.
Default 0.

Some people may want their sexy comments to be like this: >
    /* Hi There!
     * This is a sexy comment
     * in c */
<
As opposed to like this: >
    /*
     * Hi There!
     * This is a sexy comment
     * in c
     */
```

Another related format which might be of interest is the "Minimal comment map" accessible with `<leader>cm` and which produces:

```
/* Hi There!
   This is a sexy comment
   in C */
```

I wasn't able to find my preferred style unfortunately:

```
/* Hi There!
 * This is a sexy comment
 * in c
 */
```

so I opened: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/issues/379